# Enter key is not responding in chrome for onclick events

Tags: google-chrome

I am using the below user defined tag for creating an image button.
    " name="shipperLOV" onClick="javascript:showLOV('searchshipperId');" tabindex = "2" />

This image tag then refers the respective .java file to create the button as shown below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ; return false;" title=" (alt + 118)"><img src="/eTrans/images/zoom.gif" name="Button28" onclick="UIImage.onClickHandler('javascript:showLOV', 'searchserviceLevelId') tabindex="2" border="0" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" align="absmiddle" alt="Search"></a>
```

The above image button works fine in explorer and ff but when it comes to chrome the image button works only on clicking but not on pressing enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the Enter key is simulating the click on the `anchor` tag, not the `img` tag where the `onclick` handler is attached to. Your code will work if you attach the onclick event handler on the `anchor` tag instead.

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66jxQ/4/).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. That's my bad...onclick event is attached inside anchor tag itself..PS

Comment: In your example also I am facing the same issue here. On clicking  mouse it works but on pressing enter it doesn't.

Comment: You need to select it by pressing the `tab` key in that frame. When the image has a blue border around it, that's when you can press enter and it should trigger the onclick event.

Comment: you too check once for the same

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem why it could not be working for you. I made some changes to the tabindex so that the img tag is excluded. Try this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66jxQ/4/.

Comment: The 'press enter key to simulate click event' does not work in Chrome for images, but works for anchor tags. Unfortunately, this is the default behaviour on Chrome and the only way to fix it is to have a keypress event or use an anchor tag around it.

My earlier fiddle did not work because on pressing `tab` once, the image was getting highlighted since it had a tabindex assigned to it, and on the next tab press, the anchor tag got selected. On the updated fiddle, I assigned a -1 tabindex to the image so that it never gets selected on pressing tab, to ensure that u would select the anchor tag.

Comment: If your problem was solved, do accept the answer by clicking the tick icon on the left of the answer so anyone else going through the same problem may refer it.